# NAS and LAN connections

Tags: connection, nas

I have a NAS DS713, which has 2 LAN ports both plugged in to a Gigabit router. However, LAN2 is only working, I do not detect any movement of data through LAN1.

What should I do in order to correct this? My NAS is very slow...

Comment: how slow is slow? its very likely that the issue isn't your network connection, unless you are expecting links at greater than 100MBps (about theoretical max for Gigabit), and your storage on both ends of the connection are able to handle that pace. for instance files on a USB2.0 connected disk would run at most at 35MBps.

Answer (score 1):

> Coming with dual LAN ports with failover and Link Aggregation support, DS713+ ensures continual network service in case of LAN connection failure, avoiding possible disruption occurrences. Link Aggregation with trunking enhances connection speeds beyond the limits of any one single cable or port.

One of your LAN-ports (LAN1) is the one which should be plugged to your router and second one (LAN2) should be plugged to another network or another device (like your PC), you cant use both at the same time on same router.

> [Synology DS713+ overview](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS713+)
>
> [Synology Forum](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=145&t=67373)

Comment: This is true UNLESS your switch supports Link Aggregation Groups, in which case you could enable link aggregation on both the NAS and the Switch to bond together the two ports on the switch side. In that case both connections would be used, and your effective bandwidth doubled.

Comment: Could you provide some references to what you are saying please, sounds interesting for me. Thanks for you comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Link_Aggregation_and_LACP_basics  You can only perform aggregation if both your host and your switch support it. on the host side, it is often called 'Bonding' or 'Teaming' NICs, so they work as one unit. You are correct, unless the connection is teamed, you cannot connect both NAS ports to the same switched network.

Comment: If your router doesn't support it natively, you might be able to flash it with dd-wrt as it has options for LACP.